# wx.ListCtrl flickers when OnGetItemText takes too long

Tags: python, wxpython, flicker, listctrl

I'm having a problem with wx.ListCtrl using LC_VIRTUAL, and can't figure out the right way to fix it.

The problem is that the content of the control flickers if OnGetItemText() takes too long to return it's results.

The solutions I have tried so far:

- SetDoubleBuffered - If done on either the ListCtrl itself or on the parent control, it causes content to not show up at all
- disabling background erase fixes the flicker but creates redraw issues, especially when the control is resized.
- Freeze() and Thaw() don't have any effect because the control is already in the middle of a redraw.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to cache the new data before calling Refresh(). However, there are scenarios where I may need to display 100,000 records or more, so caching them ahead of time won't work.

Here is a sample I built that demonstrates the problem, though you may have to adjust the count based on your CPU speed:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import wx

class MyListCtrl ( wx.ListCtrl ):
    def OnGetItemText ( self, item, column ):
        ar = []
        for i in range ( 200000 ):
            ar.append ( i )
        return '{}'.format ( len ( ar ) )

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):
    lc = None
    timer = None

    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super ( MyFrame, self ).__init__ ( *args, **kwargs )
        self.timer = wx.Timer ( self )
        self.lc = MyListCtrl ( self, style=wx.LC_VIRTUAL|wx.LC_REPORT )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 0, 'Count1', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 1, 'Count2', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 2, 'Count3', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 3, 'Count4', width=75 )
        self.lc.SetItemCount ( 1 )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close )
        self.timer.Start ( 1000 )

    def on_timer ( self, event ):
        self.lc.Refresh()

    def on_close ( self, event ):
        self.timer.Stop()
        event.Skip()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App ( False )
    frame = MyFrame ( None )

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am experiencing the problem in both my working environments:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.2.0 msw (classic)'

Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.3.dev2680+55dda48 msw (phoenix)'
```

Comment: its hard to know without seeing the actual code, but I don't think I would put the processing workload in `OnGetItemText`. Also, I think the flickering is just a result of `Refresh`

Comment: The actual code is very simple. It typically executes something like "select * from widgets limit 1 offset 42". If you have a table with 100,000 records, you can't reasonably do that query anywhere but in OnGetItemText()

Comment: what's the purpose for calling `Refresh` every second?

Comment: The example above is an exaggerated scenario to display the problem. However, clients may want it to refresh once a second because they have multiple users and need to see the latest information, which will typically be the more recent records. I could certainly cache those most recent records ahead of time when refreshing, but it's not a general solution

Comment: if you set the individual list items instead of refreshing the whole list you won't get the flicker

Comment: I would think you could just display a screen's worth of information and load more on scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw everything on panel and set doublebuffering on the panel, flickering will be eliminated

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import wx

class MyListCtrl ( wx.ListCtrl ):
    def OnGetItemText ( self, item, column ):
        ar = []
        for i in range ( 200000 ):
            ar.append ( i )
        return '{}'.format ( len ( ar ) )

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):
    lc = None
    timer = None

    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super ( MyFrame, self ).__init__ ( *args, **kwargs )
        self.timer = wx.Timer ( self )

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panel.SetDoubleBuffered(True)

        self.lc = MyListCtrl ( self.panel, style=wx.LC_VIRTUAL|wx.LC_REPORT )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 0, 'Count1', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 1, 'Count2', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 2, 'Count3', width=75 )
        self.lc.InsertColumn ( 3, 'Count4', width=75 )
        self.lc.SetItemCount ( 1 )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close )

        self.Show(True)
        self.timer.Start ( 1000 )

    def on_timer ( self, event ):
        self.Freeze()
        self.lc.Refresh()
        self.Thaw()

    def on_close ( self, event ):
        self.timer.Stop()
        event.Skip()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App ( False )
    frame = MyFrame ( None )

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Freeze() and Thaw() aren't normally needed, but in this case behaviour of the lc is a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on another project and I finally came up with a viable solution. Looking back, my solution is exactly what Mike Driscoll's comment above is suggesting. I will provide a bit more detail here in case it helps someone.

The trick is ListCtrl's GetTopItem() and GetCountPerPage() methods. With these two functions, you can calculate the range of indexes that will be visible when the page refreshes. These are the only indexes that need to be cached when getting ready to refresh the page.

Here's a simplified example of how I implemented it.

get_row_count() just does a "select count(*)" from the table

get_row() returns the next record from the cursor if the cursor is at the right offset, otherwise it executes a new query to reposition the cursor in the right place. In my experience, a ListCtrl refreshes the items in sequential order so this works very well.

`python
    def on_list_update ( self, event ):
        self.on_begin_update() # notify subclasses that a refresh is coming
        count = self.get_row_count() # how many records will be visible?
        top = self.GetTopItem()
        bottom = min ( top + self.GetCountPerPage(), count )
        new_item_cache = {}
        for item in range ( top, bottom ):
            new_item_cache[item] = self.get_row ( item )
        self.item_cache = new_item_cache
        if count != self.GetItemCount():
            self.SetItemCount ( count )
        else:
            self.RefreshItems ( 0, count-1 )`

The above pattern typically results in only 2 sql queries being sent to the database server before the refresh starts and flicker is eliminated.

It's important to note that you want to store the item cache in a temporary variable until it's rebuilt if you use that data for other events, else you'll run into situations where the cache isn't available because a refresh is happening.